# Best open source project for audio signal processing?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Need to find if there is a open source project for audio signal processing, just as we have openCV for image processing.

Thanks

Comment: What sound transformation/processing do you require, and what license?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [my course](http://creativecomputation.co.uk/) for the more [technical part](http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas01cr/teaching/cc227/), we were introduced to signal processing, we had to use [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/) with the [audio package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/audio/index.html) and [gnu plot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/) for plotting.

[image: gnu plot]

For the [fun part](http://doc.gold.ac.uk/CreativeComputing/creativecomputation/?page_id=424) of the course used [MaxMSP/Jitter](http://cycling74.com/products/maxmspjitter/) which is a commercial project,
but there's always [PureData](http://puredata.info/) which is opensource and the Jitter equivalent would be [PD Gem](http://puredata.info/community/projects/software/gem/), but just for audio signal processing you should be fine with PureData.

[image: Pure Data scratch]

[image: Pure Data Pink Floyd riff]

In short, if you're into the number crunching bit, Octave should be fine.
We also did the image processing in Octave too, it's two dimensions as opposed to one(sound), but it's still signal processing. You can apply a high-pass or a low pass filter to an image too, you can try an echo/delay on images for fun if you like.

Pure Data is a bit different, since you patch cords instead of typing lots of code, but it's pretty fun and one of the advantages is that you can make changes live, while your patch/program is running which makes it great for fast prototyping.

Straying a bit from audio signal processing, if you're into generative music, you should have a look at some opensource projects like [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/), [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net//), [ixi](http://www.ixi-software.net/content/about.html)
or [fluxus](http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/)...some do [cool stuff with Haskell](http://vimeo.com/12127980).

**Update**
On the c++ side you can also check out [Dr. Mick Grierson's Maximilian library](https://github.com/micknoise/Maximilian) which also includes a nice little addon for [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc)

It's also worth checking out [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) and [Vamp Plugins](http://www.vamp-plugins.org/) (a lot of nice goodies there)

HTH

Comment: I think I am limited to Windows. So I guess what you have suggested above also work for windows?

Comment: @Wajih Yes! Open source software usually works on Windows/Linux/OSX, which is true for the above too.